# Adobe Illustrator | RGB vector looks all black when I import it to CMYK artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb

Colorful RGB vector I've downloaded from Vecteezy looks all black when imported to CMYK artboard. I can't change the color after importing to CMYK artboard either. How can I fix that?

---

What I've done:

1. I opened the file I've downloaded from Vecteezy on Illustrator.
2. Since it's RGB, it all looks fine.
3. Then I copy and paste it to another document (which is CMYK) on Illustrator.
4. When I pasted the vector on CMYK document, the whole vector looks black as in the 2nd screenshot above.
5. When I try to change the color, I can't do it.

[image: Colorful RGB Vector]

[image: When Converted to CMYK Artboard]

[link to the file if you want to check and see](https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/189996-abstract-orange-wave-shape-background)

Comment: The file you linked isn't the same but you will see some color-dimming going from RGB to CMYK. Check your settings to make sure that you didn't convert it to grayscale?

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the link. It's not grayscale.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you break down more in-depth the steps you are going through?

Comment: 1- I opened the file I've downloaded from Vecteezy on Illustrator.
2- Since it's RGB, it all looks fine.
3- Then I copy and paste it to another document (which is CMYK) on Illustrator.
4- When I pasted the vector on CMYK document, the whole vector looks black as in the 2nd screenshot above.
5- When I try to change the color, I can't do it.

Comment: So you are opening the document and copying it directly? Can you try to place the .eps into the new document and embed it?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of when you try to change the color... what happens?

Comment: @WELZ He did...That's the bottom picture. Do you mean a gif?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor no, like where he's changing the color what the problem is - what's not letting him? etc.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor, I could change the color when I embedded it, thanks for that. But working on the document got so clunky after embedding. That's how I did: File > Place > and opening .eps file on Illustrator. Hope it's that the correct way of doing that.

Comment: I can't replicate any problems - easily pasted into a CMYK file as colors.. and then adjusted. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozOo.gif) You aren't, by any chance, trying to change the color of the clipping mask that's present are you? There's a whole lot in that file that is NOT the actual wave.